# Why is my question considered opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216902/who-is-stronger-the-mountain-or-hodor) that compared the physical strengths of Hodor and the Mountain in GoT/ASoIaF.  It was quickly closed as being "primarily opinion-based," but I tried to make clear that I wanted to know about specific feats each character performed "on-screen" in the books or show. How is that opinion-based?

Comment: Olympic weightlifting is one of the most rigidly prescribed sports, and there are still 2 separate motions tested, and everyone is tested in exactly the same situation.  And it's still not possible to say that a given weightlifter is "stronger" than a particular NFL linebacker.  If one of them picked up a specific rock, and the other failed using the exact same technique, you can say that the first one has a stronger squat, or deadlift, or whatever.  But that doesn't mean that one or the other is "stronger" in the general case, because we don't even have a definition of what that is.

Answer (score 7):

The only reliable way to compare their physical strengths would be if they both performed *the same* feat and the success of each of them could be measured in some way. Even then, as DavidW points out in the comments, we would only be comparing strengths for that particular task and the results might be different if we looked at a different task.

Trying to compare physical strength by looking at very different feats is inherently opinion based.

Comment: Plus, that only measures the relative strengths _in that one case_; one might have more upper-body strength, the other stronger legs, and the result would go the other way if a different test were tried.

Comment: Good point @DavidW I'll edit my answer to acknowledge that.